# I am trying to display a select list from a custom controller, and i get a "Read only property 'getObjectOptions.ObjectItems''" error

Tags: visualforce

My custom controller:

```
  public class getObjectOptions {
 Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
List<SelectOption> options{get;set;}
  /**public getObjectOptions()
   {

    }**/
public List<SelectOption> getObjectItems(){
 List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
for(Schema.SObjectType thisObj : gd.values()) {
 //list<SelectOption> name = thisObj.getDescribe().getName();
 options.add(new System.SelectOption(String.valueOf(thisObj), 
String.valueOf(thisObj)));       
 }
 system.debug('options****' + options);
 return options;
 }    }
```

My VisualForce page:

```
<apex:page controller="getObjectOptions">
<apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:outputlabel value="Object Name"/>      
    <apex:selectList id="option" value="{!ObjectItems}">
 <!-- <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>-->
 </apex:selectList>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: write like  this:  in apex: public List<SelectOption> options {get;set;}

Answer (score 1):

You're binding the wrong property. Your commented-out `<apex:selectOptions>` is where your `ObjectItems` binding belongs: the `value` binding of that component should be connected to a `List<SelectOption>`.

```
   <apex:outputlabel value="Object Name"/>      
    <apex:selectList id="option" value="{!ObjectItems}">
 <!-- <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>-->
```

You do not also need

```
List<SelectOption> options{get;set;}
```

What you *do* need is a controller instance variable to hold the selected item. This should be of type `String` or `String[]`, depending on whether or not you want your select list to be multiselect, and *that* is what you bind the `value` of `<apex:selectList>` to.

That's why it needs to be read-write: it holds the value(s) chosen by the user.

There is an example in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm) for `<apex:selectList>` showing how to create these bindings.

Answer (score -2):

Please check this code:For exaplaining example taken account object has example and Type (Dropdown)

```
<apex:page controller="getObjectOptions">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:outputlabel value="Object Name"/>  
        <apex:selectList size="1" >
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!ObjectItems}"/>
        </apex:selectList>    
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Apex class:

```
public class getObjectOptions {
public List<SelectOption> getObjectItems(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('None','--None--'));
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.Type.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry p : ple)
        options.add(new SelectOption(p.getValue(), p.getValue())); 
    return options;
}   }
```